# Border height not showing correctly

Tags: html, css

I have looked for similar issues but could not find a solution. The problem comes when I insert a border which does not show the correct height. I have inserted three images and I'm trying to insert a border with no success. This is a practice to learn html and css.

HTML:

```
<div class="choices">

    <div class="choice" id="p">
        <img src="images/paper.png" alt=""> 
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="r">
        <img src="images/rock.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="s">
        <img src="images/scissors.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.choices{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative; 
} 

.choice {
  display: inline;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border: 50%; 
}
```

OUTPUT:
[output in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEn5N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `.choice` is `display: inline` that mean any height and width will have no effect. Change it to `display: inline-block` will solve the problem.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfge24z3/)

Comment: Thank you! I thought inline was the one to do it but inline-block makes more sense.